# how to convert XML from URL to HTML

Tags: plugins, rss, html, xml

I would like to know how can I, in Wordpress, convert XML URL (for example http://www.baligam.co.il/products/rss) to HTML and show it in actual.
Maybe there is a plugin for this purpose?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean convert an XML file into an HTML document?

Answer (score 1):

Using[`fetch_feed()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed) function you can fetch any rss feed on wordpress then you can loop through the result to show them (check the example on the codex page).

BTW: wordpress uses [simplepie](http://simplepie.org/) to process feeds.